# Почему "музеефикация" через "е"? И верно ли?

Tags: орфография, словообразование

А я, до появления в лопатинском словаре, правила в чужих текстах на "и"...

Comment: Которую "е" Вы правили, первую или вторую?  В составных существительных, мне кажется, всегда соединяющими гласными были "е" и "о"...

Comment: Виктор! А-а-а... а какие существительные здесь составились? О_о

Comment: Музей и -фикация (от латинского "фацере" - делать).  Правда, етсть "фальсификация", но оно - заимствованное целиком.

Comment: Но в русском нет корня фикаций. По поводу, например, газификации словарь сообщает: ифик — суффикс, ациj — суффикс.

Comment: Ну, я, видимо, не прав.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ответ Граммы.ру

На наш взгляд, речь должна бы идти о том, что в современном русском языке имеется словообразовательный элемент (его и суффиксом-то не назовешь) с ***финалью -фикациj, существующий в нескольких вариантах: -ификациj (электр-ификация, газ-ификация и т.п.), -офикациj (тепл-офикация, звук-офикация и т.п.), -фикациj (радио-фикация) и -ефикациj (музе-ефикация).*** Выбор начальной гласной этого суффиксоида определяется несколькими причинами, в частности: качеством конечного звука основы, который предшествует словообразовательному элементу, и силой аналогии со сложными словами, производными от той же основы.

Дополнение.
 [Лингвистические детективы: Электрификация и янтарь](http://www.e-reading.by/chapter.php/1006422/35/Shanskiy_-_Lingvisticheskie_detektivy.html)

Comment: А подробнее? Хотелось бы узнать, как именно на выбор гласной влияет качество конечного звук основы и в чем заключена сила аналогии со сложными словами, производными от той же основы. И всё бы это применительно к спорной "музеефикации". А вас, Серж, удовлетворил ответ Грамоты.ру? По-моему, это типичная отписка, совершенно бессодержательная.

Comment: Вера, но ведь более логичное объяснение, чем ответ Грамоты.ру.

Comment: Вера, см.дополнение.

Comment: Да. Серж, мне понравилась статья. Получается, что суффиксоид -ификациj  фактически состоит из трех частей: часть основы И + корень ФИК+ суффикс АЦИJ, который уже является русским суффиксом (новый - новация). А элемент ФИК/ИФИК уже напоминает настоящий суффикс, вот только в словообразовании самостоятельно не участвует.

Answer (score 4):

> А я, до появления в лопатинском словаре, правила в чужих текстах на
>   "и"...

И были неправы. Ибо и до  *"лопатинского"* словаря это слово в словарях писалось с ***"е".***

Посмотрите, при случае, этот словарь:

*Новые слова и значения: Словарь-справочник по материалам прессы и литературы 70-х годов / Е.А. Левашова, Т.Н. Половцева, В.П. Фелицына и др.; Под ред. Н.З. Котеловой; АН СССР. Ин-т рус. яз. М., **1984**.*

Comment: Спасибо! А есть ли какое-нито объяснение этому "е", а также прецеденты?

Comment: Объяснение? _"Е"_ -- обычная соединительная гласная (как и _"о"_).    === Да, значительно чаще перед  _"фикация"_ встречается буква _"и": электрификация, газификация_… Но во всех этих словах перед _"и"_ стоит согласная буква; слов с гласной перед _"и-фикация"_ в русском языке нет.

Answer (score 1):

**Буква И** пишется также в сложных словах  **"агрикультура и центрифуга"**, но там это не вызывает вопросов: "аргрикультура" - от латинского "agriculture", цетрифуга от лат. centrifuga,   centrum + fugere (центр + бежать), центробежный.

А почему перед ФИКАЦИЯ пишется И?  Схема образования для всех слов с этим корнем одинаковая: **основа слова усекается до согласной, а далее следует "ификация".** По такой же схеме от слова "мум/ия" образуется "мум/ификация".

Но вот со словом "музеефикация" такой вариант не проходит, так как получится "муз/ификация", совпадение основ слов "музыка и музей". Поэтому была выбрана **обычная  схема образования сложного слова с соединительной гласной Е.**

Comment: Вера, в словах с основой фикация и в таких словах  "агрикультура и центрифуга'', согласно Валгиной действует антологичный принцип структура написания.

Comment: Серж, есть два вопроса: а) почему во всех словах пишется "ификация", откуда там И? б) почему соед. гласная Е пишется только в ОДНОМ слове? Или есть еще такие слова?

Comment: Вера, я не спорю по поводу Вашего мнения об этом слове, которое вероятно имеет быть и вполне обосновано. Я хочу сказать, я словах агрикультура и словах с основой на фикация действует антологичный принцип и структура написания.

Comment: Возможно, он действует, но я не вижу как. Объясните схему образования слов на "фикация".

Comment: Валгина объясняет так.   В словах газификация, газифицировать, электрификация, электрифицировать и производных от них произносится и пишется и . Эти слова не являются сложными, так как в русском языке нет слов 'фикация', 'фицировать'. Такая же структура и принцип написания у слов центрифуга и центрифугировать ('разделять смесь на составные части при помощи центрифуги'); ср. написание сложных слов с аналогичной основой: газопровод, газогенератор, газометр, газотрон, электровоз, электрокар, электробритва, где действует общее правило.

Comment: Слово агрикультура имеет параллельное написание агрокультура, которое в современном языке является более распространенным. Это, видимо, объясняется тем, что греческий корень agros ('поле') в русских образованиях выделяется как самостоятельный. Ср. также написание слов: агробизнес, агрогородок, агроклиматический, агрокомбинат, агрокомплекс, агропромышленный, агрослужба, агрохимик, агрошкола и др., которое не противоречит общему правилу.

Comment: Понятно, что в русском языке нет слова "фикация", но как это связано с "электрИфикацией", почему бы не писать "электрофикация" или "электрефикация", где О/Е - просто гласные, а не соединительные гласные. АгрИкультура - это транслитерация, а электрИфикация - это что? Какому латинскому слову соответствует буква И?

Answer (score 0):

Грамота.ру ответила так:
   Элемент -фикация обычно присоединяется без соединительной гласной к предшествующей основе, оканчивающейся на И:

```
аммонификация, -и

амортификация, -и

амплификация, -и

атомификация, -и

аутентификация, -и

аэроионификация, -и

базификация, -и

беатификация, -и

бонификация, -и

верификация, -и

и т. д.
```

Comment: Не въеду, как это является ответом на вопрос про "музе-е/-ификацию".  Основа слова "музей" не оканчивается на "и"...

Comment: Вот именно, что не оканчивается. Поэтому в слове "музей'' соединительная гласная.

Comment: Но соединительная гласная бывает между корнями, а второго корня у нас нет.. А у газификации "газ" (предшествующая основа) окончился на "и"? О_о

Comment: Очень может быть, что это произошло по аналогии с элетр***и***фикацией.

Comment: Кстати, http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc1p/50222

Comment: _Серж: Грамота.ру ответила так_ === Грамота.ру ответила неправильно. См. обсуждение: http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=5425&p=287112&hilit=%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F#p287112

Comment: Слава, А Грамота потом никак не прокомментировала свой ответ?

Comment: К сожалению, никак.