# Как и когда произошла подмена "толочься" на "толкаться"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

**Пропал глагол "толочься" из языка?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Пропал глагол "толочься" из языка?

Не пропал. [Примеры](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F2%EE%EB%EE%F7%FC%F1%FF&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=0) из Нацкорпуса:

*Вокруг него **толокся** целый выводок врачей и студентов…* [Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого [Путешествие в седьмую сторону света] // «Новый Мир», 2000]

*Но у гроба поэта все говорили всё, не обращая внимания на то, что соглядатаи и стукачи **толклись** вокруг.* [Виктор Астафьев. Затеси (1999) // «Новый Мир», 2000]

Но употребляется действительно реже, чем лет 20--30 назад. См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ага! А столь же весомо про "продукты питания"? про "музеефикацию"? http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418821/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B5-%D0%98-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что это слова с одним значением, даже если между ними есть дарвинистическая связь (не выяснял). Я их так воспринимаю: толочься - находиться без дела в одном месте (синонимы - топтаться на одном месте, мозолить глаза, околачиваться), толкаться - находиться по какому-то делу в людной обстановке, в толпе и испытывать от этого неудобства ради какой-то надобности.

```
Что он здесь всё время толчётся?

Не пойду на концерт: там придётся стоя слушать - что за удовольствие толкаться?
```

Comment: Спасибо, я понимаю разницу между двумя глаголами. Просто наблюдаю исчезновение одного и подмену его другим. Причём не только в СМИ, но во вполне себе художественной литературе.